# Can't make ajax work in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm starting with `wordpress` and did not have a lot of problem with it until now.

I want to look into my `database` using `ajax` when a user change the value of a `SELECT` aming to update form input. Easy with `ajax` and `php` using `php` and `jquery`, but I can't seem to grasp the concept behind it in wordpress.

All the php that will be posted is directly in the file where I have my form in my plugin. For the purpose of testing I'm currently only trying to have something from the `js` in the navigator console.

**The php (wordpress):**

```
add_action( "wp_enqueue_fetch_guide", "fetch_guide" );
function fetch_guide(){
wp_enqueue_script( 'guide', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.guide.js', __FILE__ ));

    wp_localize_script('guide', 'fetchGuide', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
}

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_fetch_guide_return","fetch_guide_return");
add_action("wp_ajax_fetch_guide_return","fetch_guide_return");

function fetch_guide_return(){
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST["id"])){
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $table = $wpdb->prefix."guide";

        $guide = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id_guide LIKE ".$id.";");

        print json_encode($guide);
    }
}
```

**The js:**

```
$(function(){
    jQuery("#chooseGuide").on("change", function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : fetchGuide.ajax_url,
            type : "post",
            data : {"id":guide.value},
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(function(data){
            if(data != 0){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the function for the change event being run? Is an AJAX call being made and there is just no log? Try putting in a failure function and see if that is getting logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not pointing the ajax_url properly to your js.

Update these line

```
 wp_localize_script('guide', 'fetchGuide', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
```

to

```
 wp_localize_script('guide', 'fetchGuide', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
```

These will point the ajax_url properly and your function should work well

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress changes the .htaccess to pull all requests to itself.  If you are running ajax you will either need to put in a redirection plugin or attack the php program from outside the wordpress domain.

Answer (score 0):

Is your JS File loaded ? It seems to me that in your wp_localize_script the ajax_url is not complete. Are you properly specifying the action to be called from admin-ajax.php ?

The value of `fetchGuide.ajax_url` should be something like `admin-ajax.php?action=fetch_guide_return`. Is that correct ?

Do you have anything in the console ? I am sorry but I cannot comment yet, not enough points :p

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for yours answers. I had difficulties with the comprehension of how it worked in wordpress.

If found an answer but had to change most of how I did things.

This is what I have at the end for the JS:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_fetch_guide' );
function my_fetch_guide() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
        jQuery("#chooseGuide").on("change", function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url: ajaxurl,
                  data: {
                      action: "fetch_guide_return",
                      id: jQuery(this).val()
                  },
                  dataType: "json"
            }).success(function(data){
                jQuery("#wpgc_guide_form").prepend("<input type='hidden' name='idnumber' id='idnumber' value='"+data["id_guide"]+"'/>");
                jQuery("#name").val(data["name"]);
                jQuery("#firstName").val(data["first_name"]);
                jQuery("#mail").val(data["mail"]);
                jQuery("#phone").val(data["phone_number"]);
            }).error(function(errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            } );
        })
    </script>
<?php }
```

And the php:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_fetch_tour_return","fetch_tour_return");
add_action("wp_ajax_fetch_tour_return","fetch_tour_return");

function fetch_tour_return(){
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST["id"])){
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $table = $wpdb->prefix."tour";

        $tour = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id_tour LIKE ".$id.";");

        print json_encode($tour);

        die();
    }
}
```